# Is it possible for XML use two returns in one XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

So the question is which director has directed at least two movies and what is the title of the movies.

I know how to get the facts but i can't get my query to return both things without unnecessary iterations.

My code looks like this:

```
let $x := doc("/info.../videos.xml")/result/videos/video

for $director in distinct-values($x/director)
where count($x[director eq $director]) > 2
for $title in $x
where $title/director = $director
return ($director, $title/title)
```

Now this returns 1 director and 3 titles however the results looks like this:

Director
Title1

Director
Title2

Director
Title3

Is it possible to get it in this format

Director

Title1

Title2

Title3

With the same code? E.g. by somehow using two seperate returns in one Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The second expression can follow `$director` in the result sequence of the first:

```
for $director in distinct-values($x/director)
where count($x[director eq $director]) > 2
return ($director,  
  for $title in $x
  where $title/director = $director
  return $title/title)
```

You could also store the result of the title query in a variable:

```
for $director in distinct-values($x/director)
let $titles := 
  for $title in $x
  where $title/director = $director
  return $title/title
where count($x[director eq $director]) > 2
return ($director, $titles)
```

Comment: Thanks I did something similar! 
for $director in distinct-values($x/director)
where count ($x[director eq $director]) > 1
let $y :=
for $title in $x
where $title/director = $director
return ($title)
return($director, $y/title)

Solved my problem!